# Custom jQuery action on AJAX events

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms, comments

I'm trying to use a custom javascript event when certain actions are performed on my site, specifically things like Webforms, or Node Comments being submitted (both of which are setup to submit via AJAX), but what I'd like to do is allow the webform and comment to both perform their own internal validation before I try to act on the data.

eg, If someone tries to submit a comment on a node, but it fails validation, I don't want to react to that event, but so long as their submission is valid, then my action fires.

Originally I'd wondered if it was possible to inspect the drupalSettings code to see if I could find the AJAX commands and insert my own success code into it for example, but I don't know if this is better to do from a module, and include my own code in there to do my callback

Comment: I don't quite follow - but you can always create your own custom AjaxCommand in Drupal to trigger.

Comment: Via `hook_form_alter` simply add a custom submit funtion that runs before the default submit function.